# Code Issues Resulting in Nothing Happening and 'send' Undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here is the error I'm receiving in the console regarding 'send' undefined: https://pastebin.com/CRmZwUA4. This happens when testing our profanity filter. The word on the list is deleted and removed and the bot replies with a message stating that it was removed. This is working as it should except for the error in the console.

For the extra code not working, I'm not sure if it has to do with the error above. A few days ago the code worked fine until I made adjustments to a different section of code which was just to add in a check for the profanity filter to see if a filtered word was said by a member with a specific role. If they had the role, the filter was then ignored so they weren't blocked out. It would seem the 2 would have to do with each others but I can't figure out what the check would even affect. Again the filter worked as intended where the check was fine but the other fun code stopped working.

The code pasted below shows the fun code that stopped working. When a user besides the person being tagged says "bum" the bot replies with a fun message. That's what it's supposed to do. When any user says "bum" now, nothing happens. The concern that I have is that the testing bot used in a different server with the same code works with this perfectly fine. But the real bot on our main server is not working with the code. I even copied the file to the main bot again and restarted the bot and still nothing is happening. Sorry for the long winded post, I just want to make sure i've explained everything clearly.

```
    if (words.includes('bum')) {
        if (message.author == '<@458068171241553921>') return;
        else {
            setTimeout(function() {
              message.channel.send('Are we talking about <@458068171241553921>?!');
            }, 1500);
        }
    }



    for (let x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
        if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.id === '613427562550394891')) return;
        else {
            if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x].toUpperCase())) {
                message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
                client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
                message.delete();
                return;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your `message` event?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Could you show the `message` event where you have the code above?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by "message event". I only have this posted in the index.js file in the main function. The only extra thing would be the value of "words" which is const words = message.content.toLowerCase();

Comment: the `message` event is where you get the `message` data that you're using in your `words` variable, if you do not have one, how are you defining `words`?

Comment: That would be the code I posted in my last comment: const words = message.content.toLowerCase();

Comment: Alright, so where are you getting `message` in `message.content.toLowerCase()` from?

Comment: That's what I was told to use to get the content of a message.

Comment: Ok so quick update, I fixed that problem by removing the "return;" but now this is the error I get. https://pastebin.com/YDVZEF22

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was the new check that I had added. The check was to see if people had the role then it wouldn't respond. I had the check outside of the For loop which is what messed everything up. I placed the If statement inside the for loop instead so the new code is below

```
    for (let x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
        if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.id === '483641589193900043')) return; {
            if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x].toUpperCase())) {
                message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
                client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
                message.delete();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```